# In Dungeon World, is the Bard's Arcane Art subject to the same failure outcomes as other spells?

Tags: bard, dungeon-world

Because Arcane Art is a spell with multiple utilities for the Bard, if 1-6 risks them forgetting it, it feels quite a brutal outcome compared to a wizard suffering a similar consequence.

As a result I've been tempted to offer them the outcome of forgetting how to manipulate the spell for the specific chosen effect. E.g if the bard failed the role when attempting to heal someone 1d8, then the consequences of failure could be that they cant use arcane art to heal again until the next rest,but they could still use it for one of its other effects.

Have I misinterpreted the RAW in assuming they forget the entire Arcane Art move? In which case my hack might not be a hack, but intended.

I'm pretty new to Dungeon World but ran my first session this week, and this question came up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are understandably confused by the use of the word "spell" in the text of Arcane Art.

The brief general rules on Spells say:

> Each spell has a name, tags, a level, and an effect.

> Even if a spellcaster knows a spell, they must have it prepared before they can cast it. With some time and concentration, as described in the Commune and Prepare moves,

> One option on a 7–9 result is to have the spell revoked or forgotten.

Unlike clerics and wizards, bards have no list of individual spells with names, tags, etc. The bard also has no move to prepare spells. Therefore they don't have "spells" in the sense described by the rules; and the rules about knowing, preparing, and forgetting specific spells are irrelevant. The text of Arcane Art might be better off using the term "magical effect" to avoid confusion.

The text of Arcane Art tells you the potential drawbacks of a 7-9 result, neither of which is forgetting a spell.

Scanning through the book, I didn't see any explicit mention of forgetting spells on a 6-.  For both Cast A Spell and Arcane Art, a 6- leads to a GM move, which can be anything the GM deems appropriate.  The "Use Up Their Resources" GM move could certainly include forcing a spellcaster to forget a prepared spell (or more than one).  Arguably, it could include forcing a Bard to lose one or more of their Arcane Art options for some time.  This is entirely up to the GM.

Comment: Thanks. I confused the impact of 1-6 with 7-9, which was what started my confusion. The  outcome of 7-9 is well defined by the rules, as you've pointed out. So the 1-6 outcome is the GM hard move. Problem solved. Thanks.